# SlidingMenu slide from right

Tags: android, menu, slidingdrawer

I am  using [the SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/) to incorporate a sliding menu in my app. This works like a charm, but I would like the menu to slide from right rather than left. How do I do that?

Comment: have you been successful for the same? can you please share any work around?

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't successful. I just left it as it is.

Comment: I have done it, by the way..! Will surely post answer. Its just merely a link to Github.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code.

```
getSlidingMenu().setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
```

Comment: It says `The method setMode(int) is undefined for the type SlidingMenu`

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the sliding drawer ?! By default it's from bottom to up . But If we want change the from and to directions like top to bottom or from felt to right , we need to customise it.

Comment: I am using the SlidingMenu library which only slides from the left. I want it to slide from right.

Answer (score 0):

setMode(int) means you must input integer.. maybe you shloud use "1" or "0".so like setMode(1)

Comment: The method `setMode` itself is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go for "menu to slide from right to left."

This example project contains different demo for sliding menu (fly-in-app menu).

https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer/blob/master/library/src/net/simonvt/widget/RightDrawer.java

I have tried the same and worked exactly as I wanted..!!

Hope it helps you too.

---

Sorry in advance for putting answer containing link only, but I can't help it this time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your activity is extending `SlidingFragmentActivity`.

In `OnCreate`:

```
SlidingMenu menu = getSlidingMenu();
menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that setMode() is not available as an option in older versions of SlidingMenu, so download and import the most recent version if setMode is undefined. Once you do, you should only have to change a few imports and override a couple of required methods.

Answer (score 0):

look this example

---

```
private void initSlidingMenu(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getSlidingMenu().setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
    getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    getSlidingMenu().setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    getSlidingMenu().setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    getSlidingMenu().setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    getSlidingMenu().setFadeDegree(0.35f);

    setSlidingActionBarEnabled(false);

    // main_view
    setContentView(R.layout.content_frame);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, new SampleListFragment()).commit();

    // slide from left
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.menu_frame, new SampleListFragment()).commit();

    // slide from right
    getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.menu_frame_two);
    getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadowright);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.menu_frame_two, new SampleListFragment())
            .commit();
}
```